# Inserting array into listobjects().listcolums().databodyrange

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

A fast way of transfering data between Excel tables is to read the data into an array by looping thru the source table and then insert them into the destination table in one command. This works fine for the table databodyrange; listobjects().databodyrange = aTransfer. But when trying out doing the same for listcolumns; listobjects().listcolumns().databodyrange = aTransfer, the first number in the column is repeated down to the end of the column.

This is demonstrated in this example: [Transfering data between tables](https://1drv.ms/x/s!Ai_FpJdxgCwNheAU81OdiorLwOubCQ)

Is there a way of getting around this?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to transpose your one-dimensional horizontal array into a ***vertical*** one using the Transpose method of the Application object.  Here's an example...

```
Worksheets("Sheet1").ListObjects("Table1").ListColumns(1).DataBodyRange.Value = application.transpose(aTransfer)
```

Comment: This answers my question. I didn't realize that.